# Getting FileNotFoundException when trying to run a java program through CMD using input and output files

Tags: java, file, cmd, filenotfoundexception

When I try to run this code through eclipse, it works fine, but when I try to run it through CMD using "java MainClass >result.txt" I get a FileNotFoundException.
This is the code in question:

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass
{

```
static int cellNumber;
static int freeSpace;
static int randomResult;
static int chosen;
static int choiceSize;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = null;
    try 
    {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\users\\Alon\\workspace\\ex2temp\\bin\\input.txt"));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\users\\Alon\\workspace\\ex2temp\\bin\\result.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        chosen = getRandomInt();
        pw.printf("Choice=%d", chosen);
        pw.println();
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            cellNumber = in.nextInt();
            freeSpace = in.nextInt();

            if (sizeOfChosen(chosen) <= freeSpace)
            {
                pw.printf("%d", cellNumber);
                pw.println();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!in.hasNext())
        {
            pw.println("Cannot allocate memory");
            pw.println();
        }
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
        in.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks :)

Comment: Include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: ```C:\\users\\...``` might be hidden (I've had that problem), try putting the files somewhere else.

Comment: this is the stack trace I get in CMD : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\users\Alon\workspace\ex2temp\bin\result.txt (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:20)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the files from the ".../ext2temp/bin/.." which I assume it's Eclipse's output folder. Use the path where you have the original files.

Comment: Do you mean moving the class file and the input file one level up and try to run from there? as in - outside the bin directory?

Comment: not the class file. I'm talking about input.txt and result.txt

Comment: Exception avoided!! Thanks!! I have moved the input.txt one level up. The result.txt is formed after running, but now, when I run "java MainClass<input.txt  >>result.txt" on CMD, I get back an empty result.txt, whereas when I run it from Eclipse, result.txt has the proper data in it.

Comment: Just to clarify a few things: 1. I am supposed to run this code 20 times. At the first time, result.txt does not exist. it is supposed to be formed on the first time and by the end of it, it should hold 2 lines of data. 2. After running it the other 19 times, I should have 40 lines of data on the same result.txt file. (kind of and exercise in building a log file). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a continuous writing on the same file, I had to append text into the existing file. I have added ", true" when creating the FileWriter. Then, I created a new BufferedWriter which received the FileWriter object, and finally, changed the PrintWriter receiving object to the bufferredWriter. This way, every time I run the program, 2 new lines of data are formed below the old ones and I get a "log file".